# admob click action type that launch safari and go to the web url

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I have 2 admob ad on an ipad app.
One is 320*250
another one is 468*60

When I click the 2 two ads

I found the first one will go to the web url and launch safari, 
the second one will push up a window and display the web url.

Is it possible to change the second ad banner action to go to the web url and launch safari also?

I am not sure if I need to change the client codes or do something on admob server side setting.

Welcome any comment

Comment: if you can me pass the code then i will try for you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is something that you can control. It looks like it's a part of the AdMob SDK where the ad creative determines what type of view to put you into when a click happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have used to launch a web view safari using this code please try it. Its working fine in my Application.

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

   if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])

   NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

Thanks.